# factoring a polynomial which cannot be done with rational root test.

Tags: polynomials

I try to factor the polynomial t$^3$ $-$ 5t$^2$ $-$ 5t $-$ 1 = 0. But it cannot be done with rational root test obviously, plug in 1 and $-$1 does not work.  Any other way to solve it quickly?

Comment: Probably not..the roots are [quite complicated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E3-5t%5E2-5t-1%3D0).

Comment: A cubic with no rational root is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q.\ \ $

Comment: okay, thanks. by the way, if it is a characteristic equation for a matrix, does it mean we cannot obtain the eigenvalues?

Comment: The polynomial certainly has real roots, so the eigenvalues can be obtained. It's just that those real roots are not rational.

Comment: Is there any tricky way to do it?